# rails assets pipeline .map files in javascripts folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails

As you may know, .map files allow debuggers to more pleasantly debug minified javascript, and so .map files tend to make their appearance in javascript assets. Apparently, with the Rails assets pipeline, it attempts to add a .js extension to the .map file:

```
//= require_directory ./material_admin_theme
```

Inside that directory lives the file:

```
jquery.nanoscroller.min.js.map
```

When I load the page in chrome, I am getting a network error "404 Not Found":

```
GET http://localhost:3000/javascripts/material_admin_theme/jquery.nanoscroller.min.js.map.js 
Status Code:404 Not Found
```

Apparently, the assets pipeline is appending the .js extension to the end of the .map file. How can I fix this?